# Julia rotation and torque curve

Tags: julia, curve

I know of the idea how I would like to do it, but have no clue how to do it in Julia.
So I have graph of motor torque/rotation curve. I can collect data to arrays, like

```
torque[0,10,12,15,10,0]
rotation[0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]
```

Maybe this can be done better, but the idea is when rotation is 1000 the output is 10 and when rotation is 2000 the output is 12. Or other way. Like if I want 12Nm the output is 2000. 
That's easy to make. But what about when if I want 9Nm or 13Nm? I can make function to calculate the line between two values, but I was thinking this is common problem so maybe there is build in function for such cases. So is there?

Comment: It would be great to add a sample of code to show us exactly what you've been trying (and what you want to achieve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you mean is curve fitting you can use the [CurveFit](https://github.com/pjabardo/CurveFit.jl) package, with methods like:

```
a,b = linear_fit(rotation,torque)
```

method, which returns a and b so that

```
torque = a + b * rotation
```

If its not linear you can use poly_fit, power_fit or whatever function describes your data, but as I recall torque is related to rotation squared, so either poly_fit or power_fit should  be what you need

Answer (score 1):

To interpolate linearly between points, you can use the 
[Dierckx](https://github.com/kbarbary/Dierckx.jl), 
[Interpolations](https://github.com/tlycken/Interpolations.jl) or 
[ApproXD](https://github.com/floswald/ApproXD.jl) package.

```
using Dierckx
torque   = [0,10.,12,15,12,10,0]
rotation = [0,1000.,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]
# k=1 corresponds to linear interpolation
f = Spline1D(rotation, torque, k=1) 

using PyPlot
xs = linspace(0,6000,100)
plot( xs, [f(x) for x in xs] )
```

If you want to interpolate in the other direction, from torque to rotation,
that is more problematic because, with those numbers,
the function is not well-defined.
For instance, `10` corresponds to both `1000` and `5000`.
You can use `fzeros` to find *one* value.

```
using Roots
function g(y)
  # Only consider values between 0 and 3000
  fzero( x -> f(x) - y, 0., 3000.)
end

ys = 0:15
ys = linspace(0,15,100)
plot( ys, [g(y) for y in ys] )
```